# Kann man "jemanden kündigen"?

Tags: grammaticality, colloquial, regional

Es ist klar, dass man standardsprachlich *jemandem kündigen* kann (Dativ).

Ich höre aber ab und zu die Form *jemanden kündigen* (Akkusativ), z.B.:

> Ich wurde gestern gekündigt.

Das läuft gegen mein Sprachgefühl - schließlich kann man Verträge mit Personen beenden, aber nicht die Person selbst. Ist diese Form nun allgemein akzeptiert, nur in bestimmten Regionen üblich, oder schlicht falsch?

Bei Google ist die Anzahl der Suchergebnisse zu "[ich wurde gekündigt](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22ich+wurde+gek%C3%BCndigt%22)" und "[mir wurde gekündigt](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22mir+wurde+gek%C3%BCndigt%22)" etwa gleich. DWDS erwähnt zu [kündigen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/k%C3%BCndigen) nur die Dativ-Form. Ich habe aber diese ältere DWDS-Referenz gefunden:

> /heute auch/ jmdn. k.: nach dem Vorfall wurde der Direktor sofort gekündigt; der gekündigte Angestellte.

Inzwischen gibt es den Passus allerdings bei DWDS nicht mehr. Auch [der Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kuendigen) erwähnt nur den Dativ. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/k%C3%BCndigen) wiederum hat das Beispiel "*jemand wird gekündigt*" und deklariert es auch nicht als Umgangssprache.

Comment: Der Duden sagt: "Nur umgangssprachlich und im Österreichischen wird auch bei Personen der Akkusativ verwendet". https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Die-Verwendung-von-kündigen

Answer (score 4):

Beide, Dativ und Akkusativ, sind möglich und gebräuchlich. Das [DWDS gibt eine schöne Übersicht](https://dwds.de/wb/k%C3%BCndigen) und liefert genügend Beispiele. Dort wir auch klar, dass *kündigen* sowohl mit Dativ als auch mit Akkusativ vorkommen kann, und dass der Fall in dieser Verwendung nicht beliebig austauschbar ist:

> **Jemandem *(Dat)* etwas *(Akk)* kündigen:**
>   Die Telekom hat dem Kunden den Vertrag gekündigt.

Comment: Das, würde ich sagen, spiegelt den bundesdeutschen Standard wieder.

Comment: Man könnte den Satz »Ihm wurde gekündigt« so interpretieren, dass das Akkusativobjekt ausgelassen wurde: »Ihm wurde [der Vertrag] gekündigt.«

Answer (score 3):

Ich kann zumindest für Österreich sagen, dass der Staat, seine Behörden und alle Medien ausnahmslos diese Varianten verwenden:

> Ein Vertrag wird gekündigt
>   Eine Person wird gekündigt

Die Version *»einer Person wird gekündigt«* kann ich nirgendwo finden.

Belege:

- [arbeiterkammer.at](https://www.arbeiterkammer.at/beratung/arbeitundrecht/beendigung/Arbeitgeber-Kuendigung.html)
  Ein Vertrag wird gekündigt:

  > - Befristete Arbeitsverhältnisse können während der Befristung nur gekündigt werden, wenn ...

  Eine Person wird gekündigt:

  > - Werden Sie wegen eines unzulässigen Motivs gekündigt ...
  > - Als unzulässiges Motiv gilt z.B., wenn man wegen der Bewerbung für den Betriebsrat gekündigt wird.
  > - Dürfen Sie im Krankenstand gekündigt werden?
  > - Frau Muster befindet sich von 1.1. bis 31.1. im Krankenstand. Am 10.1. wird sie zum 17.1. gekündigt.
- [Angestelltengesetz](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/GeltendeFassung.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10008069)
  Ein Vertrag wird gekündigt:

  > § 9. (2) Wird das Dienstverhältnis vom Dienstgeber innerhalb sechs Wochen vor oder innerhalb sechs Wochen nach der Niederkunft gekündigt, ...
  >   § 21. Ein für die Lebenszeit einer Person oder für länger als fünf Jahre vereinbartes Dienstverhältnis kann von dem Angestellten nach Ablauf von fünf Jahren unter Einhaltung einer Kündigungsfrist von sechs Monaten gekündigt werden.

  Eine Person wird gekündigt:

  > § 9. (1) Wird der Angestellte während einer Dienstverhinderung gemäß § 8 Abs. 1 bis 2a gekündigt, ...

Auch in der Presse lese ich ausschließlich, dass Mitarbeiter gekündigt werden. Niemals wird Mitarbeiter**n** gekündigt:

- [Der Standard](https://derstandard.at/2000074100570/Zeitgleich-krank-Firma-kuendigte-nach-Arbeitsboykott-zehn-Mitarbeiter)

  > Zeitgleich krank: Firma in Oberösterreich kündigt zehn Mitarbeiter
- [Oberösterreichische Nachrichten](https://www.nachrichten.at/nachrichten/wirtschaft/Tesla-kuendigt-tausende-Mitarbeiter;art15,2923441)

  > Tesla kündigt tausende Mitarbeiter
- [trend.](https://www.trend.at/branchen/rechtsschutz/aeltere-mitarbeiter-kuendigungsschutz-juni-8085308)

  > Wenn ein Arbeitgeber einen Mitarbeiter um die 50 kündigen will, ...
- [futurezone](https://futurezone.at/b2b/snapchat-kuendigt-zwei-dutzend-mitarbeiter/307.393.349)

  > Snapchat kündigt zwei Dutzend Mitarbeiter

Zumindest für Österreich kann ich daher sagen, dass der Gesetzgeber, Behörden sowie Verlage von Tageszeitungen und Zeitschriften ausschließlich den Akkusativ (jemande**n** kündigen) verwenden. Der Dativ (jemande**m** kündigen) kommt nie vor.

Das entspricht auch voll und ganz dem tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch in der Bevölkerung Österreichs.

---

Die Form »den Mitarbeitern kündigen« finde ich nur in Medien aus Deutschland, z.B.

- [Welt](https://www.welt.de/kmpkt/article170249131/Chef-kuendigt-Mitarbeitern-weil-er-sie-alle-satt-hat.html)

  > Chef kündigt Mitarbeitern, weil er sie alle satt hat

Comment: Die Verwendung mit Dativ ist schon möglich, aber mE entweder bundesdeutscher Sprachgebrauch oder Fachsprache (uneinheitliche Verwendung). Akkusativ ist jedenfalls richtig & häufig.

Comment: Die Verwendung von *kündigen* mit dem Akkusativ ist im bundesdeutschen Amtssprachgebrauch ebenfalls sehr gebräuchlich. Die Praxis in der Umgangssprache ist aber eher der Dativ.

Comment: Bundesdeutsch habe ich von früher für die Person nur den Dativ im Ohr. Siehe auch das Beispiel im Duden: „meine Wirtin hat mir zum 30. Juni gekündigt“. Den Akkusativ höre ich oft, aber da ich jetzt in Wien lebe hatte ich das bisher auf regionale Unterschiede geschoben

Comment: Der Begriff »Bundesdeutsch« ist nicht geeignet, um das deutsche Deutsch vom österreichischen Deutsch abzugrenzen, denn sowohl Deutschland als auch Österreich sind Bundesrepubliken. (Beide Staaten sind Bünde die Zusammenschlüsse von 9 bzw. 16 Ländern sind, und das Staatsoberhaupt ist in beiden Staaten ein Bundespräsident.) Daher kann man sowohl das österreichische Deutsch als auch das deutsche Deutsch als *Bundesdeutsch* bezeichnen.

Comment: Oder Standarddeutsch vs österreiches Deutsch :D
Oder Deutsch vs österreiches Deutsch.
„deutsches Deutsch“ ist ein schlechter Witz nur.

Comment: @Lethargos: Österreichisches Deutsch **ist** Standarddeutsch. Es ist jene standardisierte Version der deutschen Sprache, die Amtssprache in Österreich ist. »Deutsches Deutsch« ist eine der vielen Bezeichnungen für jene standardisierte Version der deutschen Sprache, die Amtssprache in Deutschland ist. Die dritte Standardvarietät der deutschen Sprache ist schweizerisches Deutsch.

Comment: Obwohl „deutsches Deutsch“ ein Witz bleiben muss. Man muss nicht alle Tassen im Schrank haben, um sich sowas auszudenken. Man kann es zum Beispiel aber einfach „Deutsch“ nennen.
Gegebenenfalls sagt man nicht „englisches Englisch”. Aber man sagt „amerikanisches Englisch“.

Comment: @Lethargos: Auch österreichisches Deutsch kann man mit demselben Recht einfach »Deutsch« nennen. Es ist weder besser noch schlechter als das deutsche Deutsch, nur eben anders. Dann wird's aber schwierig, jenes »Deutsch«, in dem die Wörter »Marille, Matura« und »Jänner« existieren, von jenem »Deutsch« zu unterscheiden, in dem die Wörter »Aprikose, Abitur« und »Januar« vorkommen. »Englisches Englisch« ist ein schlechtes Beispiel, weil dasselbe Englisch Amtssprache auf allen britischen Inseln ist, und daher auch in Wales, Schottland, Nordirland, Irland, usw. verwendet wird. Bessere ...

Comment: ... Beispiele könnten »portugiesisches Portugiesisch« oder »spanisches Spanisch« sein, aber weil die anderen Varietäten von Portugiesisch und Spanisch in Südamerika gesprochen werden, spricht man lieber von »europäischem« oder »iberischem« Portugiesisch oder Spanisch. Man könnte auch die im arabischen Raum gesprochene Variante von Arabisch als »arabisches Arabisch« bezeichnen, um es von den in Afrika gesprochenen Varietäten zu ...

Comment: ... unterschieden, aber da hat man sich für den Begriff »klassisches Arabisch« entschieden. All diese Lösungen sind aber auf Deutsch nicht anwendbar, weil Deutschland und Österreich beide in Mitteleuropa liegen und weil keine der beiden Varietäten älter oder grundlegender ist als die andere.